# regex match for each line

Tags: php, regex

I need to match all of the lines that start with the regular expression. Sample input.

```
 #X0 alpha numeric content that  I want
 #X1 something else 
 #X26 this one as well
```

Both of these  regular expression work but for the first line. I need to match against all of the #X\d{1,2} lines.

```
     /^(\#X\d{1,2}\s+)(.*?)$/m
     /^(\#X\d{1,2}\s+)(.+)*$/m
```

What I get with any of the regex above.

```
   $pattern=  "/^(\#X\d{1,2}\s+)(.+)*$/m";
   preg_match($pattern, $content, $match);
   echo $match[1]; 
   alpha numeric content that  I want
```

Desired output.

```
   alpha numeric content that  I want
   something else 
   this one as well
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you're asking. Could you elaborate?  Also, it's not clear why the second regex is relevant, since it involves lines that start with "#O", which doesn't exist in your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag. For example:

```
$text = <<<EOT
#X0 alpha numeric content that  I want
#X1 something else
#X26 this one  as well
EOT;

preg_match_all('/^(\#X\d{1,2}\s+)(.*)/m', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match[0] . "\n";
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

corresponding to the edited question.

```
preg_match_all('/^(\#X\d{1,2}\s+)(.*)/m', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match[2] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `.*` than `.*?` for the last subpattern, because `$` is not included in `.`'s meaning.

Comment: @Kolink, Thank you for advice. I updated the code. I also remove `$`.